# Output a log file from Blender for debugging addon

Tags: python

I'm working on an addon and I'd like to be able to use Python's logging module to be able to log to an output file. While my initial purpose was to use it only for debugging the addon, I'd eventually like it to create a `.log` file in the same directory as the .blend file that's open so that users of the addon can use it in their error reports.

However, I can't figure out how to configure the logging module. I can `import logging` and call `logging.warning()` to print out a message to the system console, but if I make a call like `logging.debug()` in an operator, it doesn't print anything (it apparently doesn't take into account the `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` that I set at the beginning of the file as soon as I import the logging module).

I would eventually also like to use `logging.basicConfig()` to set the log file output location, but when I do this, it doesn't write the log file to where I specify. Any ideas of how to tackle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `logging.debug()` or `logging.basicConfig()` you are using the *root logger*. But in Blender where your addon is just one addon of many, you shouldn't try to "take control" of the root logger like this. The logging modules provides a nested hierarchy of loggers, so you can  use a logger unique to your addon.

This may be why `basicConfig` isn't working for you, it ["does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).

The usual pattern for this is

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

def my_fun():
    logger.debug("this is a debug message")
```

(See [Configuring Logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) for how to configure formatting, etc.)

---

If you want to write to a file in the .blend's directory, you can use a [`FileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler). But because the directory could change, for example if the file is saved to a new location, we can attach the handler for the duration of a single operator execution only.

```
class MyOperator(Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.my_op"
    bl_label = "Test Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        log_path = bpy.path.abspath("//my-operator-log.txt")
        log_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path)

        try:
            logger.addHandler(log_handler)
            do_my_operation(context)
            return {'FINISHED'}

        except e:
            logger.error(e)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        finally:
            logger.removeHandler(log_handler)
```

If you want to further customize this, you can write a custom handler. For example, [Godot reports warnings and errors through the GUI with `op.report()`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-blender-exporter/blob/b8b883df64f601acc4c40110e99631422a4978ff/io_scene_godot/export_godot.py#L61-L76).

---

Btw grepping for `logging` in the addon directory is a good way to find out how other people are using it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the thoughtful answer! I feel it's a little cumbersome having to configure the logger in each operator. Could I avoid that if I wanted to only write to the temp directory of the OS? I tried configuring that with Python's tempfile module, but I didn't have any luck getting it to write out a file.

Comment: Yes, just do `logger.addHandler(logger.FileHandler(path_to_tmpfile))` once when you configure the logger. You can also write a custom handler to send it basically wherever you want.

Comment: @AnsonSavage -- don't forget to mark this as "Answer Accepted" if you agree with it.  This gives credit to the person who spent time answering, increases their *reputation* on the site, and drives more people with similar questions to read this answer.

Comment: @scurest Okay, neat! Is there any way to do that in a single place for the entire addon? Or does it have to be in each module?

Comment: @scurest I just did some tests and your method is working for me! Thanks again. Yeah, if there is any way to configure the logger once for the entire addon and not for each individual module, that would be awesome to know. If not, that's also okay.

Comment: If you are putting `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` in each module, you should only have to configure the top-level logger in the `__init__.py` file because the child loggers will propagate to their parent.